# Consume only first message from Kafka Queue?

Tags: apache-kafka

is there a way to consume only first message from kafka queue out of 1000 messages? I am trying to implement same in java. And I do not have any backend DB.

Comment: If you want to consume only the first message, then Kafka is not the right choice. You should've explained your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you can't do it, there is [KIP-41](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-41%3A+KafkaConsumer+Max+Records) that will solved this.

Although if you know the size of the element you want, there is a property in the consumer called fetch.message.max.bytes that you can set 
to the size of the elements you want to poll, and each poll will return only one record.